# jQuery jScrollPane Plugin IE 8 scroll is very slow with large data/content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, jscrollpane

jQuery jScrollPane Plugin in IE 8 scroll is loading and scrolling very  slowly. It was same in IE 9 also, but since i have applied the fix mentioned in 
[jScrollPane causes slow script warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135948/jscrollpane-causes-slow-script-warning) it is working OK in IE 9 but in IE 8 the issue is still there.
Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the speed of scroll inside the code of jscroll library. Its better if you write a code to read content height and setting a scroll amount according to height

Comment: Hi.. its not about the speed of the scrollbar but the Javascript being unresponsive.. it has to do with some operations inside the Jscrollpane plugin as it was in the case of IE9..but thx for the suggestion..:)